# Excel Index / vlookup between varied row amounts

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to use a vlookup / index to pull some numbers. Sample data attached:

**A:** merged cells (the number is stored in the top of cell of the merge)

**B:** Only numbers I am looking for from this one are the totals in blue

**E:** Number to lookup

**F:** Totals (expected numbers shown in green)

I have done something similar in the past just cant see how I got it to work.

**Note: The amount of rows for each number in column A could vary the smallest they will appear is as 2 rows e.g. rows 4 / 5 but could go up infinitely.**

If anyone knows how I could get the expected result that would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or,

try this formula solution of which criterias in column D were NOT in the same order as in Column A. (as per the OP's comment).

In `E1`, formula copied down :

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,A:A,0)+MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(1,N(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,A:A,0)+1):A$14<>"")),0)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may ***try*** this formula as well, works with ***any order*** using `INDEX()`, `AGGREGATE()`, `LOOKUP()` & `ROW()` Functions,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `I1`

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$14,
AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$1:$B$14)/
(H1=LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$14),ROW($A$1:$A$14)/
($A$1:$A$14<>""),$A$1:$A$14)),1))
```

---

Let me explain why this works,

• `LOOKUP()` Function creates an array of the `Column A` values

```
=LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$14),ROW($A$1:$A$14)/($A$1:$A$14<>""),$A$1:$A$14)
```

Refer Column `L`

[image]

---

• Select the above formula and press `F9` Function Key, you will find it creates an array of **12345**, **43643**, **23245**, **98989** for the number of times it has a value in `Column B`

```
{12345;12345;12345;43643;43643;23245;23245;23245;23245;23245;98989;98989;98989;98989}
```

[image: CHECK_IMAGE]

---

• Next I did a `Boolean Check` i.e. whether it matches with my criteria or not, and returns an array of `TRUE's` & `FALSE's` respectively

[image: TRUE_FALSE]

```
={FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}
```

---

• To return the relative position of my criteria in an array I simply did the one as shown below, which gives me the respective row numbers,

Refer Column `L`

[image: EVALUATING]

```
=ROW($A$1:$A$14)/(H1=LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$14),ROW($A$1:$A$14)/($A$1:$A$14<>""),$A$1:$A$14))
```

---

• As you can see on doing above it returns along with some errors as well, hence we wrapped the whole within an `AGGREGATE()` function

--> Where `14` refers to **function_num** that is `LARGE()`,

--> Where `6` refers to **options** that is `Ignore Error Values`,

--> Where `array` is the

```
ROW($A$1:$A$14)/(H1=LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$14),ROW($A$1:$A$14)/($A$1:$A$14<>""),$A$1:$A$14))
```

--> and lastly `[k]` we need largest of all in the array, which shall return me the row number, therefore, in the above it will return `10` for **98989** as in cell `H1` and if you see `E1` it will return `3` **12345** and so on so forth for others as well.

---

Therefore when we have got the row number or the position we wrapped the whole within an `INDEX()` Function to get our desired output respectively!

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$14,
AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$1:$B$14)/
(E1=LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$14),ROW($A$1:$A$14)/
($A$1:$A$14<>""),$A$1:$A$14)),1))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The formula below *would* work

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$1:$B$14,MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$14,0)-1),INDEX($B$1:$B$14,COUNT($B$1:$B$14)))
```

*if* the values in column D were **always** in the same order as those in column A:
[image: screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

Comment: Thanks, that works! is there a simple way to make this work where the order wouldn't matter or likely to be much more complex?

Comment: There probably is a way, but I doubt it would be simple, and would depend on your version of Excel - the simplest non-formula solution would be to copy your data, paste as values, to get rid of the merging, use [special cells -> blanks](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html) to fill down the orders, and then use SUMIF() on the resultant range